# Select option выпадает вверх. Как сделать чтобы выпадало вниз?

Tags: html

select option выпадает вверх. Как сделать чтобы выпадало вниз?

```
 <select id="day">
    <option value="0" selected="1">День</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если он выпадает вверх, это означает только то, что внизу недостаточно места. Обеспечьте его-и он будет падать вниз.